# Get Animation states from an Animator in Unity3d

Tags: animation, unity-game-engine

I've used Animator to create two animation states, I want to change the speed of these animations at run type. How can I get these animations at run time and change their speed? Do I have to attach Animation component or Animator is enough?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use GetCurrentAnimatorStateInfo() to get current state info.

"Base Layer" is your base layer's name

```
var currentState : AnimatorStateInfo = animator.GetCurrentAnimatorStateInfo(0);
if (currentState.nameHash == Animator.StringToHash("Base Layer.Player_standing"))
{
    Debug.Log("I'm standing");
}
```

Comment: It seems this is the only reliable way, but I think it's quite dumb.

Answer (score 1):

```
//get animation:

animator = GetComponent<Animator>();
AnimatorStateInfo stateInfo = animator.GetCurrentAnimatorStateInfo(0);

//get animation speed, add animation speed

Debug.Log("StateInfo length:  "+stateInfo.length);

if(Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.A))
{
    animator.speed += 1f;
}
```

Comment: What does this answer add, the [answer from 3 years ago](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22753322/7111561) didn't have? I doesn't even have any explanation on it